# Bit manipulation in c

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

```
int samp=0;

for(i=0;i<=31;i++)
{
  samp=samp|1<<i;
}
printf("\ %d\n",samp);
```

output:

```
-1
```

Why is it giving -1 if I loop till `i<=31` (setting all 32 bits to 1)?
When I loop only `i<31` it is giving 2147483647. Why is it so?

Comment: Try it with `unsigned int samp = 0;`.

Comment: Remember the `|=` operator:  `samp |= 1 << i;`.

Comment: @  embedded_guy i changed it to unsigned int samp=0, but still getting -1 only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your printf statement you are using **%d**, which prints a **signed integer**. The output is correct due to the sign bit being set.

Change the format string to **%u** and it will display the **unsigned integer** value. No more sign bit and the value you are looking for.

You should be using an **unsigned int** anyway for **samp**.

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because the first bit is the sign bit.

When the sign bit is `1`, the number is negative, and `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` happens to be the 32-bit representation of the number `-1`.

You may want to check out [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Answer (score 0):

Because of signed integers in the modern computers represented as two-complement code:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement